# How to express Number type in ExpressionAttributeValues using AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am performing a query from AWS Lambda against a DynamoDB table.  When using the AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient it does not appear to convert an "N" data type correctly.  I get the error "ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type". When I use AWS.DynamoDB and explicitly specify the "N" type, the query works.  Both "event" values are strings.

I'd prefer to use AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.  Any suggestions?

--> NOT WORKING

```
let dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

let params2 = {
    TableName: "TABLENAME",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#o = :owner and #s = :sortkey",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#o" : "owner",
        "#s" : "sortkey
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":owner" : event.userId,
        ":sortkey" : event.objPartitionKey
        }
    };
     const data = await dynamodb.query(params2).promise();
```

--> WORKING

```
    let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

    // configure the dynamoDb query parameters
    let params = {
        TableName: "TABLENAME",
        KeyConditionExpression: "#o = :owner and #s = :sortkey",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#o" : "owner",
            "#s" : "sortkey"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":owner" : {S: event.userId},
            ":sortkey" : {N: event.objPartitionKey}
        }
    };
     const data = await ddb.query(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DynamoDB DocumentClient uses javascript types to determine what DynamoDB type to marshall to. I can only assume that event.objPartitionKey is a javascript String. It needs to be a JavaScript number to be marshalled correctly to a dynamoDB "N" type field. To get the first code snippet to work, first convert event.objPartitionKey to a number using: `parseInt(event.objPartitionKey)`

See AWS Documentation to understand how the DocumentClient marshalls JS types to dynamodb types:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html